# How to access nested iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to send post message ([window.postmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage)) to iframe.

currently its working if i have single iframe inside parent page.But I want to make it work for nested iframes.
Criterias are :

- I can just add listener code in last leaf iframe.
- Do not know length of iframe nesting.
- Need both way communication , from parent to child also by leaf iframe to parent.

I am sick of third part iframes , please suggest me some appropriate solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to send post message to iframe"? Do you need to submit a form and have it [target](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#attr-fs-target) an iframe? That doesn't require any JS.

Comment: No , soryy i didn't explain properly , I meant to know about https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage.

Answer (score 1):

Quite old question but, I had a similar problem and I worked out a solution. It may help others in future.

We can always `postMessage` any `iframe` in nested `iframe`'s in both directions using `.parent` and `.frames[i][j][k]`

For example, if you want to post message to first `iframe` inside third `iframe`, you could do this:

```
window.frames[2][0].postMessage(msg, "*");
```

See more information at https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

> For iframes, we can access parent/children windows using:
>
> - window.frames – a collection of nested window objects,
> - window.parent, window.top are the references to parent and top windows,
> - iframe.contentWindow is the window inside an  tag.

The postMessage interface allows windows to talk to each other no matter which origin they are from. So, it’s a way around the “Same Origin” policy. See more information [here](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#cross-window-messaging).

Comment: Yes, @DavidBradshaw. postMessage is the way to communicate cross-domain. Adding a line from the reference, in my answer above.

Comment: I meant walking the frames like that (`frames[0][2]`)

Comment: Yes, the indexing/accessing works cross-domain, but what one could do with it is limited if the origins are different

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an event system that propagates events up or down yourself.

Adding something like this in all of your iframes will propagate the events down.

```
//create a jquery object to use the bind/trigger event system
var vent = $({});

function trigger(event, args) {
    //trigger for the current iframe
    vent.trigger(event, args);

    //propagate down for all nested iframes
    $.each(getAllIframes(), function(i, iframe) {
        iframe.trigger(event, args);
    });
}

function bind(event, callback) {
    vent.bind(event, callback);
}

function getAllIframes() {
    return $("iframe").map(function(){
      return this.contentWindow;
    });
}
```

You can implement the event bubbling in similar fashion but will have to have some sort of initialization logic that binds to all child frames.

Comment: I guess your method is useful to get all the frames in same page.I need to know number of frames inside a frame.